# How to show Java dialog when cron runs the Java program?

Tags: cron

I've done a little java program that ends showing a dialog after doing some other tasks like reading from a web and writting on a file.
My goal is to make it run everytime my system starts with 90 seconds delay. (@reboot sleep 90; ...).
It allready does all the job well (it creates the file that I want correctly), but the problem is that it doesn't show the dialog. If I run the script manually it works as I want.

This is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
javac /home/eneko/workspace/Comprobación\ página/src/Main.java
java -classpath /home/eneko/workspace/Comprobación\ página/src/ Main
exit 0
```

And this is what I've written on crontab (I've set it to run every minute just to try if it works without rebooting):

```
* * * * * export DISPLAY=:0 && /home/eneko/Documentos/scriptComprobacionPagina.sh
```

I thought the problem was with `export DISPLAY=:0` as it's explained [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=185993). But after trying it I'm afraid I'm missing something. 
I can't even run amarok as in the example.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried adding it to .xinitrc?

Comment: Hi Matthew, thanks for your answer. I read here (https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xinitrc) that this file "is used to execute desktop environments, window managers and other programs". What's the point of including the script here? The program runs correctly every minute with my settings but it doesn't show the Java dialog. I'm fairly new to these issues. I've tried `cp /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc ~/.xinitrc` and then I've put `sh /home/eneko/Documentos/scriptComprobacionPagina.sh` inside .xinitrc but it doesn't work.

Comment: Cron is for starting **background** jobs, not for programs with an UI. And your problem is that access to the X Server is limited: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_authorization

Comment: @EnekodelaTorre - since you said that `My goal is to make it run everytime my system starts with 90 seconds delay`, I thought you want to run it _once_, at startup.

Comment: @MatthewRock, you were right, I assumed that cron was the only way to solve my problem, but I was wrong, thank you too. I tried adding the script to .xinitrc but I did something wrong and my desktop crashed. I think I've to learn more before trying to modify that again. Finally,  I found that my goal could be achieved adding the script  to Startup Applications and now it works as I wanted.

Comment: @EnekodelaTorre Glad to hear you found solution. Consider adding it as an answer and accepting, so that others who encounter similar problem in the future might benefit from it too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assumed that cron was the only way to achieve my goal, but I was wrong because cron is for starting background jobs. Then I tried to create a `.desktop` file and adding it to Startup Applications and it worked.
The file is in `~/.config/autostart` and this is what it contains:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Comprobacion
Exec=/home/eneko/Documentos/scriptComprobacionPagina.sh
Icon=
Comment=Sin comentario
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
```